# How to create multiple Submit buttons with Flask forms?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

**Problem** : I want to do the whole thing with the Form_Setting class in the forms.py file. Here I have defined the 4 submit buttons. I then use the buttons in the settings.html. In the routes.py file I want to react when they are pressed. However, at the moment it is still so that I can react with form.validate_on_submit() only generally on the submit. **How can I distinguish which of the submit buttons were pressed to then perform different actions?**

**routes.py**

```
from page import app
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for
from page.models import Settings
from page.forms import Form_Setting
from page import db



@app.route('/settings', methods=['GET','POST'] )
def Settings_Page():

    form = Form_Setting()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
      save_email =  Settings(email_adress=form.email_adress.data) 
      db.session.add(save_email)
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('Settings_Page'))
    
    return render_template('settings.html',form=form)
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField

class Form_Setting(FlaskForm):
    email_adress = StringField(label='Email')
    dooralarm_time = StringField(label='Türalarm')
    minimum_temp = StringField(label='MinTemp')
    maximum_temp = SubmitField(label='MaxTemp')


    submit_email = SubmitField(label='Eingabe')
    submit_door = SubmitField(label='Eingabe')
    submit_temp_max = SubmitField(label='Eingabe')
    submit_temp_min = SubmitField(label='Eingabe')
```

**settings.html**

```
{%extends 'base.html' %}

{% block ActivSettings%}
    active
{% endblock %}

{% block css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/style.css')}}"/>
{% endblock %}


{% block title %}
    Einstellungen
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="setting-page">Einstellungen</h1>
            <!--Email Adresse-->
            <div class="row ">  
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center" style="height: 8vh;"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                            <h3 class="setting-label">E-mail</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <form  method="POST" class="form-register flex-fill d-flex" >
                                <!--Schutz gegen CSRF-->
                                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                                {{ form.email_adress(class="form-control", placeholder="E-Mail") }}
                                {{ form.submit_email(class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary", style="background-color: #6941c6; border:none; color: #f9f5ff; margin-left: 1vw;" )}}
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="divider">
                </div>  
            </div>

            <!--Türalarm Zeitintervall-->
            <div class="row ">  
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center" style="height: 8vh;"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                            <h3 class="setting-label">Türalarm Zeitintervall</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <form  method="POST" class="form-register flex-fill d-flex" >
                                <!--Schutz gegen CSRF-->
                                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                                {{ form.dooralarm_time(class="form-control", placeholder="Zeitintervall") }}
                                {{ form.submit_door(class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary", style="background-color: #6941c6; border:none; color: #f9f5ff; margin-left: 1vw;" )}}
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="divider">
                </div>  
            </div>

            <!--Temp. Schwellwert Minimal-->
            <div class="row ">  
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center" style="height: 8vh;"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                            <h3 class="setting-label">Temp. Schwellwert Minimal</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <form  method="POST" class="form-register flex-fill d-flex" >
                                <!--Schutz gegen CSRF-->
                                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                                {{ form.dooralarm_time(class="form-control", placeholder="Temp. Minimal") }}
                                {{ form.submit_temp_max(class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary", style="background-color: #6941c6; border:none; color: #f9f5ff; margin-left: 1vw;" )}}                      
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="divider">
                </div>  
            </div>

            <!--Temp. Schwellwert Maximal-->
            <div class="row ">  
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center" style="height: 8vh;"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                            <h3 class="setting-label">Temp. Schwellwert Maximal</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <form  method="POST" class="form-register flex-fill d-flex" >
                                <!--Schutz gegen CSRF-->
                                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                                {{ form.dooralarm_time(class="form-control", placeholder="Temp. Maximal") }}
                                {{ form.submit_temp_min(class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary", style="background-color: #6941c6; border:none; color: #f9f5ff; margin-left: 1vw;" )}}                                                
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="divider">
                </div>  
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
{% endblock %}
```

**Webseite**
[The result for the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwhby.jpg)

Comment: What is the reason for using one form with 4 submit buttons instead of 4 separate forms? Do you need to process all 4 values every time any of the buttons is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through `request.form` using the variable name of the submit button.

```
from flask import request

if 'submit_email' in request.form:
    # do something
elif 'submit_door' in request.form:
    # do something
```

Be sure that the form will still validate properly `form.validate_on_submit()`

Comment: Where would be the best place to validate? If I do the validation as a parent if query I get many errors because the individual fields have different validators independently of each other.

Comment: I believe best practice would be to use multiple form instances. You could also add the Optional() validator to all the form fields and then instruct your backend to only modify data that is present.